# Incorrect insert syntaxis SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a Temporal Table:
`create table #T_Table(id int,name nvarchar(80),value float);`

I am executing dynamic SQL to insert to `#T_Table` the select result from `@table_name` like this:

`SET @template = 'INSERT #T_Table (id,name,value) VALUES('+Cast(@counterI as nvarchar)+', '+ @fieldFromTableName +', Select [value] = SUM('+@fieldFromTableName+') FROM '+ @table_name +')';

EXEC (@template);`

So if I print`@template`:
`INSERT #T_Table(id,name,value) VALUES(1, x1, Select [value] = SUM(x1) FROM Mytable);`

What is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here´s the INSERT you should build:

```
INSERT #T_Table(id,name,value) 
SELECT 1, 'x1', SUM(x1) FROM Mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest a `SELECT` inside a `VALUES` set of values.

Change `VALUES` to `SELECT` and get rid of the brackets.  You also need to make sure `x1` is wrapped in quotes, e.g.:

```
INSERT #T_Table(id,name,value) 
SELECT 1, 'x1', Select [value] = SUM(x1) FROM Mytable;
```

To get quotes around `x1` you will have to put double quotes in your quoted string to escape them: e.g. `SET @quotedString = 'not quoted, ''quoted,'' not quoted'`